# How to create a user group in Windows 7 machine that belongs to a domain?

Tags: windows-7

I need to share a few folders with a group of people (my team at work). I want to create a group that contains those users so I don't need to enter each of their names when creating shared folders. How can I do this? Is it even possible, given that I am not the admin of the domain network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to have Admin rights on your local PC and the computer will need to be part of the domain. You will need to have an account on this domain assuming you're already logged in with your account it should be fine.

Start by doing the following:

- Access Computer Management
- Access System Tools, Local Users and Groups, Go to Groups
- Create a New Group and Select Add Users - From here insure that the location is set to the domain and then start typing the name of the users you wish to be part of this group.
- Select Ok and then create.

Once this is created go to the directory you wish to share and do the following:

- Right click on directory and select Properties
- Select Sharing
- Select Advanced Sharing
- Click Share this folder
- Name the share, and the select permissions
- Select Select Add and set location to your computer name, one at the top and select ok
- Type in the name of the group you created earlier, select ok and set the permissions for read or modify depending on the access you wish to provide and select ok 2 more times.
- Go to the security tab and select Edit then Add
- Enter the locally created group again with the same method previously.
- And then set the permissions for that account, select ok twice and then your done

The folder will be accessed via `\\computername\share`